# Problem in running C++ program using DOS box?

Tags: c++, compilation, dosbox

The same program which is running in Windows XP is not running in Windows 7 using DOS box.
I get an error in opening stdio.h conio.h? How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: Please refer this Link. It will be helpful to you. [http://blog.bestsoftware4download.com/2010/02/how-to-install-turbo-c-on-windows-7-64bit/](http://blog.bestsoftware4download.com/2010/02/how-to-install-turbo-c-on-windows-7-64bit/)

Comment: which c++ compiler/version are you using. Can you show some code (the minimal code that demonstrates the behavior)? Based on this anyone's guess is as good as yours given the current info in your question

Comment: And people say backwards compatibility isn't an important feature of Windows. Hah!

Comment: **You forgot to upgrade your compiler when you upgraded Windows.** You're about 20 years behind the curve.

Comment: You also forgot to upgrade your keyboard to one with upper case.

Comment: Seriously though, your question has nowhere near enough detail for you to get a good answer. You need to state exactly what you are running and precisely what error you get.

Answer (score 2):

There's a difference between running and compiling a program.  The tags on your question imply that you mean compiling when you write "running".  Reading your question with that alteration:  The problem is that you've not installed your compiler correctly on the second machine, so that it can locate its header files such as `<stdio.h>`.  It really has almost nothing to do with the version of Windows NT that you are using, and everything to do with installing the compiler correctly with the right directories, environment variables, and whatnot.

Comment: Or the fact that the header isn't included in the compiler he's using. Which seems more likely, given the context. Either way, good call on differentiating running and compiling.

Answer (score 0):

1. I think you are using old TC compiler . I will suggest you to switch to new compiler gcc. You can download Codeblock IDE with mingw.
2. If you don't care about the first point. Than make sure you have correct include path in TC . go to options and check include directory..